# Combining text and image features with different scales

Tags: bert, feature-scaling, vgg16

I have computed text features using [SBERT][1] and image features using VGG-16. The text features range from -1.58 to 1.58, whereas the image features range between 0 and 521. I would want to concatenate the text and image features and use them to compute cosine similarities. However, as you've probably noticed, the difference in scale would mean that the image features would completely dominate the text ones.

My idea was to use something like sklearn's MinMaxScaler and scale down the image features to the same scale as the SBERT computed features; however, I'm not sure if this is the best solution for my case since other [answers][2] here suggest normalizing both features. In my case, I would say that the text features are **more important** than the image ones.

[1]: https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers
  [2]: [Creating a feature by combining 2 features with different units?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39742/creating-a-feature-by-combining-2-features-with-different-units)

Answer (score 1):

In my view, you found out appropriate answer because this article consists of regular normalization and weighting.

I think [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39742/creating-a-feature-by-combining-2-features-with-different-units) normalized both features, but this is somewhat useless according to your project as normalization takes automatically place when computing cosine similarities.

So you can convert text feature ranges to image feature ranges and I suggest this example.

```
text_feature_v2 = [ele / 1.58 * 260.5 + 260.5 for ele in text_feature]
concated_feature = [*text_feature_v2, *text_feature_v2, *image_feature]
```

Here I concatenated two identical text features for enhancing its importance.

I will provide my python code.

```py
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm
from random import randint


def rand_text_feature(dimension=4):
    """Returns dimension-sized array between [0, 521]."""
    res = [randint(0, 521) for _ in range(dimension)]
    return res

def rand_image_feature(dimension=4):
    """Returns dimension-sized array between [0, 521]."""
    res = [randint(0, 521) for _ in range(dimension)]
    return res

def cos_sim(arr1, arr2):
    """Returns Cosine similarity of two arrays."""
    return dot(arr1, arr2)/(norm(arr1)*norm(arr2))

# prepare two pairs of features
text_feature1 = rand_text_feature()
image_feature1 = rand_image_feature()

text_feature2 = rand_text_feature()
image_feature2 = rand_image_feature()



# Prints similarity of texts and images.
print('similarity of two texts')
print(cos_sim(text_feature1, text_feature2))
print('similarity of two images')
print(cos_sim(image_feature1, image_feature2))

# compute cosine similarity traditionally
feature1 = [*text_feature1, *image_feature1]
feature2 = [*text_feature2, *image_feature2]

print('similarity of concatenated feature')
print(cos_sim(feature1, feature2)) 

# compute cosine similarity regarding my proposal
enhanced_feature1 = [*text_feature1, *text_feature1, *image_feature1]
enhanced_feature2 = [*text_feature2, *text_feature2, *image_feature2]

print('similarity of concatenated feature enhancing text')
print(cos_sim(enhanced_feature1, enhanced_feature2))
```

And this was the result.

```bash
similarity of two texts
0.8618949874358144
similarity of two images
0.598022653964154
similarity of concatenated feature
0.7335241784245647
similarity of concatenated feature enhancing text
0.7767832080432862
```

#### If text is more similar than image, my algorithm prints higher similarity,

#### otherwise, prints lower similarity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please mention what formula did you use to do this upscaling? Also why are we scaling the text features up and not scaling the image features down? Can you also provide me some theory for concatenating the same features twice? I’ve never seen this method of enhancing importance before

I’m new to this so excuse the questions

Comment: Text feature ranges between [-1.58, 1.58] and image feature ranges between [0, 521], so I converted text feature range into image feature range. Here, I scaled up anyway, you can scale down. I think two results are similar. And I concatenated two text features so that `concated_feature` has two identical text features and one image feature. This way, I provided more importance to text. I cannot explain the reason, but I did like this according to my experience.

Comment: how did you come up with this approach of concatenating the same two features? Did you find this on the internet or was it shown to you by someone else. As I said I've never seen this before so I would like to research it myself but I have no starting point.